# stack running out of memory in recursion

Tags: recursion

I have a question about following algorithms,

```
public static int sum(int x){
    if (x == 0 || x==1)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else 
        return x + sum(x-1);

}

public static double factorial(int x)
{
    if (x==0 || x==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        return (double)(x*factorial(x-1));
    }
}
```

I ran sum (10,000) and factorial(10,000), I have got stack overflow error from running factorial(10,000) but not sum(10,000). why is that? Aren't the number of lines (function call) in the stack memory the same?

Comment: Probably because 10,000! is orders of magnitude larger than the number of atoms in the universe.

Comment: @musical_coder: doesn't matter.

Comment: @musical_coder Shouldn't matter, the number will just wrap back around.

Answer (score 1):

The big difference I see is that one stores `int`s, the other `double`s on the stack.

`double` uses more space (that is, usually.. you haven't tagged the question with a language).

Comment: In fact, the discrepancy goes away when we change the return type of `factorial` to `int` (assuming Java).

Comment: the thing is if I change the type to int the answer of factorial (10,000) will be 0, because it exceeds the range of int

Comment: @user2277918 Even with double the answer you get will be wrong. 10000! is approximately equal to 2.8 * 10^35659 which is well outside the range of a `double`.

Comment: Also noteworthy: `factorial` returns a double but the calculation is done on *integers*, making the late cast to return type worthless.

Comment: @Jongware: nope, calculation is done `int * double`, which implicitly converts `int` to `double`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: (after re-reading) You are correct! The double value only lives on the stack, while the parameter `x` is passed on as an integer -- but that's irrelevant to the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Stack space required for each recursion step depends on amount of temporary objects and their types. The same is about parameters and returned item.

As everybody points above, two functions have a difference with returned type - this is the cause of faster stack consumption.